# Strange result in subquery and grouping of MariaDB (this is absolutely bug)

Tags: mariadb

**select VERSION()**

| VERSION() |
| --- |
| 10.3.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 |

**Table "kas"**

| id | tanggal | notran | rekanan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155 | 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | 130 |
| 185 | 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | 130 |

**Table "kasdetil"**

| id | master | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 156 | 155 | 100000.0 |
| 186 | 185 | 10000.0 |
| 188 | 185 | 30000.0 |

**Table "rekanan"**

| id | nama |
| --- | --- |
| 130 | OWNER |

**1st Query:**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, jumlah
from kas m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join kasdetil d on d.master=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 10000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 30000.0 |

**2nd query (subquery & grouping => ok):**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, jumlah
from (select * from kas) m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join (select master, sum(jumlah) jumlah from kasdetil
    group by master) d on d.master=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 40000.0 |

**3rd Query (add where clause => wrong result):**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, jumlah
from (select * from kas where tanggal between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31') m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join (select master, sum(jumlah) jumlah from kasdetil
    group by master) d on d.master=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 140000.0 |

**4th query (commenting "join rekanan" => ok):**

```
select tanggal, notran, jumlah
from (select * from kas where tanggal between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31') m
-- join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join (select master, sum(jumlah) jumlah from kasdetil
    group by master) d on d.master=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | 40000.0 |

**5th query (not using subquery of "kasdetil" => ok ):**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, sum(jumlah) jumlah
from (select * from kas where tanggal between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31') m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join kasdetil d on d.master=m.id
group by d.master
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 40000.0 |

**6th query (using trim(d.master)=m.id => ok)**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, jumlah
from (select * from kas where tanggal between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31') m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join (select master, sum(jumlah) jumlah from kasdetil
    group by master) d on trim(d.master)=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 40000.0 |

**7th query (using d.master+0=m.id => ok)**

```
select tanggal, notran, r.nama, jumlah
from (select * from kas where tanggal between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31') m
join rekanan r on m.rekanan=r.id
join (select master, sum(jumlah) jumlah from kasdetil
    group by master) d on d.master+0=m.id
```

| tanggal | notran | nama | jumlah |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-15 | HO-NK-2106-00001 | OWNER | 100000.0 |
| 2021-06-24 | HO-NK-2106-00002 | OWNER | 40000.0 |

I am very sure this is a bug of MariaDB.

**Note: type of column id and master = *varchar*. When I change to *integer*, everything fines.**

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @drum, I want using query like the 3rd query for readability, optimization and efficiency (probably also speed) reason. Using 6th and 7th query are very slow for big data. But anyway, this is a bug and should be solved as soon as possible.

Comment: @drum
About type of column id and master, I prefer using varchar rather than integer for flexibility of it's value.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, then talk to the maintainers of the project. SO is the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You're using BETWEEN on a varchar, but expecting date functionality.  that's an undefined requirement, and so I'm not surprised that you get an undefined result.  Try casting/converting the varchar to a date.